# What are some ways to remove hardened thinset from drain pipes?

Tags: plumbing

We have a drain trap in a floor that is clogged with thinset and/or cement grout. The pipes are almost impossible to reach so replacement is a last option.

Comment: You should probably revise to tell us what kind of pipes we're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You're really not going to get away from excavating the P-trap and replacing it. Anything that would damage concrete would almost certainly damage the pipes as well (PVC or metal)

Answer (score 1):

Muratic acid will dissolve the thinset. The problem will be getting the sand out of the trap. After rinsing the acid out of the trap a shop vac may help to get the sand out. I had a renter dump a bunch of sand in the sink and it was tough getting it cleaned out so the drain would work again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it will be the last option - even if you persevere with a hammer and chisel, you will most likely crack the pipe leaving a leak...